# How to run python program automatically even if system restarted

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

I want to run my python API continuously (means program API will all-time active if call then it work) even if a system restarts my python API automatically restart.

I have API URL: `http://localhost:8002/city_id_pred?id=1,2` through this URL calling python API.

Program:

```
import web
import pyodbc
import re
import numpy as np
#from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

urls = (
      '/city_id_pred?', 'Predict'
      #'/', 'MyApplication'
  )

class Predict(web.application):

    def run(self, port=8080, *middleware):
        func = self.wsgifunc(*middleware)
        return web.httpserver.runsimple(func, ('0.0.0.0', port))

    print("Start class...")
    def GET(self):

        #here prediction model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Predict(urls, globals())
    app.run(port=8002)
```

Please suggest

Actually, I want to run on window server but currently using in windows OS.

Comment: That's much depend on your OS, less so on the fact that the script is python.

Comment: Then you've got to run a Python HTTP server on that port throughout, on your localhost.

Comment: If your on a windows based system, you can just make a executable and put it in the Startup folder. Do everyone the system restarts, your program will launch automatically.

Comment: How to make executable? what about the server?

Answer (score 0):

As @Mubarak said, you basically want to convert it to a .exe and then add that .exe to startup.
I would recommend that you do this by using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) and then following [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/) tutorial on how to add that .exe to your startup.

Comment: I am getting error while converting py to exe: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` by using ` pyInstaller code.py` on cmd. `code.py` is as same in question

Answer (score 0):

Following step will help you:

1. Make your python code like example.py
2. Convert example.py to example.exe file by using **auto-py-to-exe** https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/
3. Open Task Schedular in your window system [image]
4. Create Task->Gentral Tab ->Give Name,Location
5. Trigger Tab->Bigin the Task->On Startup
   [image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Following given steps,.

1.Convert your python file to .exe format(https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)

2. Make simple batch file to run the .exe file which your python file.

@echo off

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\"
```

Start chrome.exe

```
start – "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE"

"C:\Work\MUO\How to Batch Rename.docx"

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player"

start vmplayer.exe

exit
```

Hope your understood,....

Comment: can you please explain more 2 steps to `start vmplayer.exe`?

Comment: Same way run your python .exe convert file instead of vmplayer.exe

Comment: getting error while converting: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`